# How to modify how TinyMCE format text

Tags: html, css, tinymce

TinyMCE color formating is putting in to span tag,
now I need when ever user change color for a text add
one extra character
(for those who may wonder way I need this, read this: [Inserting HTML tag in the middle of Arabic word breaks word connection (cursive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069247/css-formating-cursive-word-breaks-it))

so this is how TinyMCE normaly format text:

```
<p><span style="color: #ff6600;">forma</span>tings</p>
```

this is how I need to be:

```
<p>X<span style="color: #ff6600;">forma</span>tings</p>
```

so before any span I need to add one extra character.

I was searching throug TinyMCE source but I couldn't find where it assembly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totaly understand your need for a word-joiner.
Depending on the browser you might be able to insert this character using a css-pseudo element - in this case before: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp

Your tinymce content css (use the tinymce init setting [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css)) should contain the following:

```
body span:before {
    content:'\2060'; // use '\00b6' to get something visible for testing
}
```

**UPDATE: Approch2:**

You can do this check to enter your word joiners:

```
var ed = tinymce.get('content') || tinymce.editors[0];

var span = $(ed.getBody()).find('span:not(.has_word_joiner)').each(function(index) {
  ed.selection.select(this);
  ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '\u2060<span class="has_word_joiner">'+this.innerHTML+'</span>'); // you might want to add the formerspan attributes too, but that is a minor issue
});
```

You might need to call this using an own plugin on special events.

Comment: That is working for every character except word joiner,
because it breaks word as you already  seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069247/css-formating-cursive-word-breaks-it .

When I go to show html in TinyMCE, it doesn't show in it any character which is inserted with :before. However as I previously sad it is working for every character except word joiner :(.

Comment: hmm, right. pseudoelements won't be in the saved tinymce content. i will think about another approch and update my answer

Comment: I am building virtual keyboard, in tinyMCE I have onKeyPress event,
so when user press some key on keyboard I am changing it with other letter. I put your code above in onKeyPress event handler and in console I am geting the message: ed is undefined

Comment: ed represents your editor instance. you just need to put your editor id there instead of "content"

Comment: var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor; //slove that problem,
but now it is not inserting word joiner as well as other characters,
in the way I implement it.

Comment: @user637307 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2664/discussion-between-thariama-and-user637307)

Comment: you will need U+2060 instead of U+200D
the first one does not break, the second does - both are word joiner

Comment: here is my files http://www.mediafire.com/?16h76vceg2et2cm
All files that I am modifing are:
Keysboard.html
/Script_Logic/Keyboards.js
Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_init.js

with using \2060 it doesn't import it at all.

You can try just type 'S' and then try to select some of it and color it you will how it breaks word.

Comment: theEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '\u2060<span class="has_word_joiner">'+this.innerHTML+'</span>\u2060');

Comment: the above would be the right code to use. But the main problem is that your characters are not inside any spans (your handler should be called right after the assignment of color happens). Actually, this leads to the non-insertion of the word-joiner.