# Making a letter bold in cursive scripts like Arabic script

Tags: html, unicode, arabic, right-to-left, persian

Consider Persian word سیب (/si:b/ apple). I want to make middle letter of it bold. Using the following code

```
س<b>ی</b>ب
```

produces

س **ی** ب.

How I can prevent the separation of the letters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting HTML tag in the middle of Arabic word breaks word connection (cursive)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069247/inserting-html-tag-in-the-middle-of-arabic-word-breaks-word-connection-cursive)

Comment: Also look at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=236135

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no predefined way for the browser/OS to connect Normal س to a Bold ی. It's somehow similar to have س and ی in different font sizes.

One workaround is to use [Kashida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashida) before and after the letters:

سـ**ـیـ**ب

Another workaround is to use [Zero-width joiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner):

س‍**‍ی‍**ب

Answer (score -1):

As you describe, you do not want space between `b` tag, so you can use `margin` and `padding` set to 0.

Comment: At the moment, HTML tags break Arabic Cursive Joining, so this is not a solution.