# Arabic text zero width joiners not working between elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I am trying to implement a "Smart Search" feature which highlights text matches in a div as a user types a keyword. The highlighting works by using a regular expression to match the keyword in the div and replace it with

```
<span class="highlight">keyword</span>
```

The application supports both English and Arabic text. English works just fine, but when highlighting Arabic, the word "breaks" the word connection on the span rather than staying a single continuous word.

I'm trying to fix the issue by using 3 separate Regex expressions and adding zero width joiners appropriately to each case:

- Match at the Beginning of a word

  `var startsWithRegex = new RegExp("((^|\\s)" + keyword + ")", "gi");`

  `var newSpan = "<span class='highlight'>$1&zwj;</span>&zwj;";`
- Match in the Middle of a word (Note: There can be multiple middleOf matches in a single word)

  `var middleOfRegex = new RegExp("([^(^|\\s)])(" + keyword + ")([^($|\\s)])", "gi");`

  `var newSpan = "&zwj;$1&zwj;<span class='highlight'>&zwj;$2&zwj;</span>&zwj;$3&zwj;";`
- Match at the End of a word

  `var endsWithRegex = new RegExp("(" + keyword + "($|\\s))", "gi");`

  `var newSpan = "&zwj;<span class='highlight'>&zwj;$1</span>";`

Both startsWithRegex and endsWithRegex appear to work as expected, but middleOfRegex is not. For example:

> **للأبد**

transforms into:

> **ل‍‍ل‍‍أ‍بد**

when the keyword is:

> **ل**

I've tried other various combinations of `&zwj;` but nothing seems to be working. Is this a limitation of webkit? Is there another implementation I can use to get my desired result?

Thanks!

A few extra notes:

- This is only happening for Webkit based browsers (Chrome specifically in my case) and we cannot use an alternative. I believe this bug is the root cause of the issue:
  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6148
- This question is an extension on these two stackoverflow questions:

  [Inserting HTML tag in the middle of Arabic word breaks word connection (cursive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069247/inserting-html-tag-in-the-middle-of-arabic-word-breaks-word-connection-cursive)

  [Partially colored Arabic word in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155849/partially-colored-arabic-word-in-html)

Comment: I've worked on this issue before and believe it is caused by the first webkit bug you linked to... which has been open for a whopping 10 years. The &zwj; is helpful, but I'm not sure it will get you all the way.

Comment: Seems like an issue with the special lam+alif rendering. If I put a `&zwj;` between "lam" and "alif", it breaks viewing in multiple browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Arabic language is a special case because the letter has different forms depending on its position in the word, I remember I solved such a problem using its Unicode, each letter’s form has different Unicode. 
You can find the Unicode table here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode
You can get the Unicode value using

```
var code = $(selector).text().charCodeAt(0);
```

Comment: I was not able to get the desired result by using charCodeAt in the text. When comparing the unicode values between different forms of a letter, I was finding that they are the actually same value. Here's a jsfiddle I wrote to demonstrate what I'm seeing
https://jsfiddle.net/avfpjnc7/

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Drew: I don't think you are missing anything. I can't see how this answer would help you fix the problem.

Comment: Please try to use unescape(); and escape(); they might help.

Comment: unescape() and escape() are depracated from javascript 1.5

I tried encodeURI() and decodeURI() but it's the same problem. Same unicode character, same encoding

Comment: I hope that will help, as long as regex expression function does not match the different forms of the same letter and it considers them different letters. I will make my smart search based on CharCodeAt because it returns the same Unicode. For example: if I write “abc” in search box, the script will search the database for records where the Unicode of the first three letters equal to the Unicode of “abc”. 

Another thing I will do if possible, I will switch off the highlight style in search box and I will show only the suggested results as full phrases without span in the drop menu.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to separate this ligature, but to extend the `<span>` tag to enclose the entire lam+alif structure for highlighting.

According to http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch23.pdf#G25237, ZWJ works as ZWJ+ZWNJ+ZWJ between ل(lam) and ا(alif). It should be rendered as a connected lam followed by a connected alif (ل‍‌‍ا), not like the required ligature (لا).

Seems to me most browsers/fonts adhere to this requirement.

My answer applies to other ligatures as well, if you use them in your application (non-required ones, e.g.: mim + mim).