# How to connect Arabic words in separate html elements

Tags: html, unicode

```
<h1 dir="rtl">
  <span>ضرب&#x200d;</span><span>ه</span>
</h1>
<h1 dir="rtl">
  <span>ضربه</span>
</h1>
```

Top is my attempt and the bottom is the expected format.

It's slightly different from [Inserting HTML tag in the middle of Arabic word breaks word connection (cursive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069247/inserting-html-tag-in-the-middle-of-arabic-word-breaks-word-connection-cursive).

See http://jsfiddle.net/wokb8rvu/ for working example

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to connect Arabic words in separate html elements?

Comment: I think it's unreasonable to expect any sort of ligatures to work between disjoint elements. Why can't you just eliminate the `<span>` and `</span>` tags?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I would like to apply javascript to each word individually, e.g. display information about that word when a user hovers over it. If you have an alternative, that should be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this ? tell me why do you want to put them in seperate spans ? maybe i could help more

there is multiple kind of that character :

`&#1577;`  --> ة

`&#1607;`  --> ه

"ة" - "ه"

```html
<span>ضرب&#1577</span>
```