# applying style on contextual characters breaks the words

Tags: html, css, arabic, farsi

I have problem in Arabic and Farsi characters as they have contextual (connetced) characters, When I want to indicate a keyword, the words that contain that keyword , break to smaller words. My question is how to apply css styles on keywords without breaking main words?

As you see in the following examples the character س is being separated from next character when I apply style on it.

```css
.redColor{color:red}
.redBg{background:red}
div{font-size:26pt}
```

```html
<div>
کلمات به هم پیوسته
<br>
کلمات به هم پیوس<span class="redColor">ته</span>
<br>
کلمات به هم پیوس<span class="redBg">ته</span>
</div>
```

Comment: found a duplicate, let me know if it fixes your issue

Comment: Yes it fiexed the issue. But I am wrting a new answer with more specific details on that question @TemaniAfif

Comment: I have added a complete answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069247/inserting-html-tag-in-the-middle-of-arabic-word-breaks-word-connection-cursive/55218489#55218489
@TemaniAfif

Comment: great, but no need to edit your question ;) since there is the duplicate banner both questions are linked.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to consider gradient coloration that you adjust in size/position to have the needed coloration. The drawback is that you need to correctly find the different values that will change depending on the chararacter you want to target and the font properties:

```css
.redBg {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) left/23px 100% no-repeat;
}
.blueBg {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(green,green) 40px 0/32px 100% no-repeat;
}

.redColor {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) left/23px 100% no-repeat,
    #000;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.blueColor {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(green,green) 40px 0/32px 100% no-repeat,
    #000;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}



div {
  font-size: 26pt;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="redBg">
  کلمات به هم پیوسته</div>
  <br>
  <div class="blueBg">
  کلمات به هم پیوسته</div>
  <br>
  <div class="redColor">
  کلمات به هم پیوسته</div>
  <br>
  <div class="blueColor">
  کلمات به هم پیوسته</div>
```

You can also easily scale to multiple background in order to target more character in the same sentence:

```css
.redBg {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) left/23px 100%,
    linear-gradient(pink,pink) 80px 0/25px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.blueBg {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(green,green) 40px 0/32px 100% no-repeat;
}

.redColor {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) left/23px 100%,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) right/45px 100%,
    #000;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.blueColor {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(green,green) 40px 0/32px 100% no-repeat,
    #000;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}



div {
  font-size: 26pt;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="redBg">
  کلمات به هم پیوسته</div>
  <br>
  <div class="blueBg">
  کلمات به هم پیوسته</div>
  <br>
  <div class="redColor">
  کلمات به هم پیوسته</div>
  <br>
  <div class="blueColor">
  کلمات به هم پیوسته</div>
```

Another idea is to duplicate the text where you can easily apply the needed styles and you cut one of the text using overflow (you won't have line break with this method)

```css
.redColor:after {
  color:red;
  width:25px;
}
.blueColor:after {
  color:blue; 
  width:30px;
  text-indent:-42px;
  left:42px;
}

div {
  font-size: 26pt;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
div:before,
div:after{
  content:attr(data-text);
}

div:after {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="redColor" data-text="  کلمات به هم پیوسته">
</div>
<br>
<div class="blueColor" data-text="  کلمات به هم پیوسته">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solves the problem for special case by try and error and seems to be a partial solution for special word and needs to be completed by adding heavy calculation of the rendered ouput to find the exact place of keywords. Also for repeated keywords inside a single word, it would be so complicated. I vote up the answer and wait for other answers to find the best solution.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour that's the arabic language ... not easy to deal with, I have edited to add more ways (still not generic)